# Handling mysqli_num_rows returning false

Tags: php, mysql, return-value

I have code in my site that currently tries to connect to an empty database, as this site gets more users interacting with it this database will contain data.

The code below is meant to return information about a users car project, if there is anything to return, as not all users will have signed up will have a project. Some may just sign up to leave comments etc.

Whats the best way for the code to handle display result if found, but skip the section if theres not a match from the SQL?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE username='$u'";
$projects_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
// Fetch the user row from the query above
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($projects_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
     $description = $row["description"];
     $first_posted = $row["first_posted"];
     $updated = $row["updated"];
     $vehicle = $row["vehicle"];
     $donor = $row["donor"];
     $transmission = $row["transmission"];
}
```

I have tried to user mysqli_num_rows etc but it returns the same style error as theres nothing there.

Comment: Are you sure your database connection worked?  (ie is $db_conx something valid?)

Comment: false means failure. Which means something failed before hand, and you didn't properly (or at all) handle it. And note that a query which returns 0 rows is **NOT** a failure. an empty result set is a perfectly valid result set.

Comment: That could well be where my issue is, I assumed I was getting the boolean return due to there being no result. $db_conx is working as I am getting other sections of data returned, another reason I assumed it was due to the lack of content within the database itself. 

I'll go back over and reinvestigate my code

Comment: There was a misspelling within the naming of my database table, Marc B if you would like to copy and paste you comment as an answer I'll then accept it.

Comment: Glad you found the issue. You should added a few rows of data (known number of) then you would have known that it was never getting that far. You can always delete them before going live. Good luck.

Comment: I will remember to do that next time I create a system like this, you live and learn :D